# set updatedby only if any eniy data has changed

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

In my customer entity I would like to save a changedByUserId field. I only want to set this field if one of the other fields of customer has really changed. If I allways set it I force EntityManager to update the customer table because I set the changedByUserId field.

```
@Entity
@Table....
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private Long cusID;
    @Column
    private String cusNAME;
    @Column
    private Date changed;
    @Column
    private Long changedByUserId;

    @PreUpdate
    private preUpdate() {
        changed = new Date();
        // cannot set changedbyUserId here because no entitymanager 
        // available where i can query the id
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to tell EntityManager not to check for changes in the changedByUserID field?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Interceptor class which extends `org.hibernate.EmptyInterceptor` and overrides its methods in order to achieve what you wanted. You can read more about it from [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/manual/en-US/html/events.html). For example:

```
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] currentState, 
            Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) throws CallbackException {
        if ( entity instanceof YourBaseEntityClass) {
            int updatedPropertyCount = 0;
            for ( int i=0; i < propertyNames.length; i++ ) {                
                if ("UPDATED_ON_PROPERTY".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                    currentState[i] = new Date();
                    updatedPropertyCount++;
                }
                if ("UPDATED_BY_PROPERTY".equals( propertyNames[i] ) ) {
                    currentState[i] = Context.getContextUserId();
                    updatedPropertyCount++;
                }
                //if the conditioon passes both the properties have been updated
                //break from the loop 
                if(updatedPropertyCount == UPDATE_TOTAL_COUNT){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            //even if either of them modified returned true after the end of the loop
            if(updatedPropertyCount >0){
                return true;
            }           
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using javax.persistence api and not hibernate. any other alternatives?